# Binding commands without PRISM

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, prism, delegatecommand

Since I started using MVVM, I've always used PRISM's DelegateCommand class for binding commands in my view models to button commands in my views. I believe Telerik also has an equivalent of DelegateCommand.

My question is, is there a built in alternative to using 3rd party frameworks such as prism and telerik. If I'm throwing together a quick throwaway application I may not want the hassle of installing packages from NuGet. Is there a way to achieve the same thing using a Func or an Action or a delegate?

Comment: AFAIK, there aren't any implementations already made for you in the framework. However, I personally like MVVM Foundation. You could just copy the RelayCommand class to your project, and now you have what you're asking for. Technically, it's still a 3rd party framework, but if you only need the one class, it's the same as writing it yourself: https://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you still need a `Command` class that implements `ICommand`. **However**, you can write your *own* `DelegateCommand` really easily (citation, I wrote this off the top of my head in less than a minute):

```
public class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
     private Action<object> execute;

     public DelegateCommand(Action<object> executeMethod)
     {
          execute = executeMethod;
     }

     public bool CanExecute(object param)
     {
         return true;
     }

     public void Execute(object param)
     {
         if (execute != null)
             execute(param);
     }
}
```

Use and enjoy! You could take an additional `Func<bool, object>` parameter if you wanted custom `CanExecute` behavior instead of returning true.

Note, if you *really* don't like `null` as the function, and want it to throw if you try it, just use this constructor instead:

```
     public DelegateCommand(Action<object> executeMethod)
     {
          if (executeMethod == null)
              throw new ArgumentNullException("executeMethod");

          execute = executeMethod;
     }
```

Comment: @ConnellOD, additionally, I would suggest you to check in the `Execute()` method whether `CanExecute()` returns true and act respectively.

Comment: @dymanoid While there is a threading hazard there, typically `CanExecute` is used to simply disable the UI control, and isn't invoked from `Execute`. Not that there is anything wrong with doing that, it just isn't standard to do so.

Comment: @dymanoid. Wouldn't implementing CanExecute() require the command to have knowledge about how it will be used? Until now I've always just had a bool CanExecute property in my view model that I bound to the IsEnabled property of the UI control. Is there an advantage to using CanExecute() instead?

Comment: @ConnellOD A command object *should* know if it is currently able to run. Thats what `CanExecute` is for.